# can i change value of an array with another query result

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

in my code, I have a list of found items that have an array of ids of another list, and I want to change each of the ids in the array to their name, I used for and forEach loop to go through each of the ids and change them to the item name like this

```
/* the found list i have the array in */
List.findOne({ name: _.kebabCase(req.params.name) }, { _id: 0, __v: 0 }, (err, foundList) => {

    /* going through each value in the array */
    foundList.idsArray.forEach((id, i) => {

        /* trying to find the matching row in another collection with the value of the array index */
        Table.findById({ _id: id }, (err, foundTable) => {
           
            /* here i am trying the change the value, but it wont work */
            foundList.idsArray[i] = foundTable.name;
        });

    });

    /* here I am trying to render the page with new values, but it has not worked */
    res.render("preview", { details: foundList });

}).lean();
```

I can change the value wherever else in the forEach except in that Table.find

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. Have you tried about `async/await` for and also using `map` instead of `forEach` for returning new array and avoiding to commit any changes to original one?

Comment: i tried 
```List.findOne({ name: _.kebabCase(req.params.name) }, { _id: 0, __v: 0 }, (err, foundList) => {
    foundList.newArray = foundList.faculties.map(element => {
        Table.findById({ _id: element }, (err, foundTable) => {
            return foundTable.name;
        });
    });
    res.render("preview", { details: foundList });
}).lean();```
do you see any problem in it?

Comment: Hmm, it seems that this solution have a problem, when you `return foundTable.name` it just returns to the inner callback function and not the `map` callback function then the map returns nothing for that element in new array. I will write a message with `async/await` and `map` method, see it works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a better and clean code, hope it works (Just make sure that this code got put in a function that has `async` keyword behind it):

```
const foundList = await List.findOne({ name: _.kebabCase(req.params.name) }, { _id: 0, __v: 0 }).lean();
const newList = [];
for (const id of foundList.idsArray) {
    const foundTable = await Table.findById({ _id: id });
    newList.push(foundTable.name);
}

res.render("preview", { details: newList });
```

Comment: you cant store Mongoose result like that, it must be a function to get the result

Comment: @Rawand Have you tried it? I'm using it everyday actually.

Comment: @Rawand There was a little mistake for `newList = foundTable.name;`, it has to be `newList.push(foundTable.name);`. Would you try it now?

Comment: I combined some of my ideas with your idea and it solved my problem, thank you so much